# Laravel Queue Job Running Immediately

Tags: laravel, queue

I have a laravel queue setup to a database. When I run `dd(env('QUEUE_DRIVER'))` I get `database` back. When I create a job it is run right away. I would like the job to be queued until I run `php artisan queue:work`. What do I need to do to have the job not run right away. Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

Dispatch Code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
        $job = new UpdateJob("");
        dispatch($job);
}
```

Job Code:

```
public function handle(){
    sleep(30);
    SlackApi::SendMessage("Job!");
}
```

When I run this I get a slack message every 30 seconds. But none of these jobs are being stored in the DB.

**Edit 2:**

Even when I add `->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10))` to the job the job is still run right away.

Comment: When you put job into queue it will run as quick as possible. Job feature created for purpose when you have to do many tasks so they are queued in the queue and will perform one by one. Maybe this article can help you: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-queue-job-delay-doesnt-work

Comment: Show me your lines of code where you dispatch your job

Comment: @vietnguyen09  See Edit

Comment: You not run `queue:work` but still see new record inserted in your DB?

Comment: I did not run queue:work the job is just being done. And I don't see anything in the DB.

Comment: Ok, you must know that your sleep code will not work because your `dispatch($job);` will send a command to `queue` server and job class will not be touched by your request. 

Now I need to know what happen when you run `queue:work`? Do you run `php artisan queue:table` and  `php artisan migrate` yet?

Comment: When I run `queue:work` the terminal hangs as it runs. When I run the command and then run the cron I still don't see anything in the db. Yes I have the jobs table in my DB.

Comment: This video might help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVIby9rVlZQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to come from upgrading from v5.1 to v5.4 I added `Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class` to my providers in app.php and that fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Is any supervisor running? if the supervisor is configure the queue will be take care of the job as son as it's added to the queue. if you want a delayed dispatch of the job you must specify the delay. Take a look into https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#delayed-dispatching for more details